# python: how to have a property and with a setter function that detects all changes that happen to the value

Tags: python, properties

I have a two properties which holds lists. Whenever any item in this list changes, I would like the other list to update itself. This includes the statement `obj.myProp[3]=5`. Right now, this statement calls the getter function to get the whole list, gets the third item from the list, and sets that to 5. the `myProp` list is changed, but the second list never gets updated.

```
class Grid(object):

    def __init__(self,width=0,height=0):

        # Make self._rows a multi dimensional array
        # with it's size width * height
        self._rows=[[None] * height for i in xrange(width)]
        # Make `self._columns` a multi dimensional array
        # with it's size height * width
        self._columns=[[None] * width for i in xrange(height)]

    @property
    def rows(self):
        # Getting the rows of the array
        return self._rows

    @rows.setter
    def rows(self, value):
        # When the rows are changed, the columns are updated
        self._rows=value
        self._columns=self._flip(value)

    @property
    def columns(self):
        # Getting the columns of the array
        return self._columns

    @columns.setter
    def columns(self, value):
        # When the columns are changed, the rows are updated
        self._columns = value
        self._rows = self._flip(value)

    @staticmethod
    def _flip(args):
        # This flips the array
        ans=[[None] * len(args) for i in xrange(len(args[0]))]
        for x in range(len(args)):
            for y in range(len(args[0])):
                ans[y][x] = args[x][y]
        return ans
```

Example run:

```
>>> foo=grid(3,2)
>>> foo.rows
[[None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]
>>> foo.columns
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
>>> foo.rows=[[1,2,3],[10,20,30]]
>>> foo.rows
[[1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]
>>> foo.columns
[[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30]]
>>> foo.rows[0][0]=3
>>> foo.rows
[[3, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30]]
>>> foo.columns
[[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30]]
```

If you look at the last three lines, this is where the actual problem occurs. I set the first item of the sublist to three, but `foo.columns` never updates itself to put the 3 in its list.

So in short, how do I make a variable that always updates another variable, even when it's subitem is being changed?

I'm using Python 2.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not *setting* `foo.rows` on the offending line - you're *getting* it, and then modifying one of it's members. This isn't going to fire the setter. With the API you're proposing, you would need to return a list that has getters and setters attached as well.

You'd do better to not use the rows and columns properties to set entries, and add a `__getitem__` method like this:

```
class Grid(object):

    def __init__(self, width=0, height=0):
        self._data = [None] * width * height;
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def __getitem__(self, pos):
        if type(pos) != tuple or len(pos) != 2:
            raise IndexError('Index must be a tuple of length 2')
        x, y = pos
        if 0 <= x < self.width and 0 <= y < self.height:
            return self._data[x + self.width * y]
        else:
            raise IndexError('Grid index out of range')

    def __setitem__(self, pos, value):
        if type(pos) != tuple or len(pos) != 2:
            raise IndexError('Index must be a tuple of length 2')
        x, y = pos
        if 0 <= x < self.width and 0 <= y < self.height:
            self._data[x + self.width * y] = value
        else:
            raise IndexError('Grid index out of range')

    @property
    def columns(self):
        return [
            [self[x, y] for x in xrange(self.width)]
            for y in xrange(self.height)
        ]

    @property
    def rows(self):
        return [
            [self[x, y] for y in xrange(self.height)]
            for x in xrange(self.width)
        ]
```

The broken line then becomes:

```
foo[0, 0] = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

if you simply return your `rows` or `columns` list, then you'll never have any control about what happens when an item is changed.

one possibility would be not to provide properties to get/set the lists directly, but provide setters/getters for an item at position x/y.

a nice version would be to have `__setitem__`/`__getitem__` and have them accept a tuple, that way you could acces the elements using `foo[x,y]` and `foo[x,y] = bar`.

an other way would be to return a wrapper around the list that detects whe an element is changed, but then you'll also have to do that for every nested list.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you look into using [numpy](https://numpy.org/).  In particular, the [transpose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) method gives a "view" of the underlying matrix with the axes transposed, meaning that if you change one then the other will change.

If that doesn't suit your needs, then the only way I can see to make the API you want work is to define the "rows" and "columns" methods to return custom "view objects" that don't actually store the data, but that point back to some private (shared) data in the grid object itself.  These could be list-like, but would not support some operations (e.g., append or clear).