# Trigger method when child is added to tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, tree

Suppose i got the following piece of python code to create a forest containing a bunch of trees.

```
NEXT_INDEX = 0

class Node:
""" A node of a tree """

    def __init__(self):
        # Each node gets a unique id
        self._index = NEXT_INDEX
        NEXT_INDEX += 1
        # any node may have an arbitrary number of children
        self._children = list()
        self._parent = None

    def add_child(self, node):
        node._parent = self
        self._children.append(node)

    def __str__(self):
        return "node {}".format(self._index)


class Forest:
""" A bunch of trees """

    def __init__(self):
        # contains the root nodes of a whole bunch of trees
        self._trees = list()

    def add_node(self, node):
        # the new node will be the root node for a new tree in self._trees
        self._trees.append(node)

    def find_node(self, idx):
        """
        Search all trees in self._trees for a node with index = idx
        and return that node.
        """
        # Implementation not relevant here
        pass

    def on_add_child(child):
        # should be executed each time add_child is called on a node with the
        # new child as a parameter
        print("on_add_child with child = {}".format(child))
```

I would like to execute a method, "on_add_child", each time a child is added to **any** node in **any** of the trees stored in Forest._trees.

**Important**: The print statement has to be in the Forest class. In the real code Forest maintains a search index of nodes and whenever a new child node is added, the new node has to be added to the search index. Adding a reference to Forest to Node (so that Node.add_child could call Forest.on_add_child) is unfortunately not an option either, because it would introduce a circular dependency between Node and Forest.

**Example**: Say i executed the following code

```
forest = Forest()
node_0 = Node()
node_1 = Node()
node_2 = Node()
node_3 = Node()
node_4 = Node()

# We add the first node to the forest: It will become the root of the first tree
forest.add_node(node_0)

# Add node_1 as a child to node_0; This should execute on_add_child(node_1) and
# print "on_add_child with child = node 1"
forest.find_node(0).add_child(node_1)

# Should print "on_add_child with child = node 2"
# => on_add_child is also triggered when we add a child to a non-root node
forest.find_node(1).add_child(node_2)

# Create a second tree
forest.add_node(node_3)

# Should print "on_add_child with child = node 4"
forest.find_node(3).add_child(node_4)
```

**How can this be accomplished?** I am aware of python properties and i have found several related questions about how to use properties together with python lists (eg. [Python property on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564798/python-property-on-a-list), [Python decorating property setter with list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16380575/python-decorating-property-setter-with-list), [python: how to have a property and with a setter function that detects all changes that happen to the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665874/python-how-to-have-a-property-and-with-a-setter-function-that-detects-all-chang)), but in my case it is not just a list, but also a tree structure and i couldn't get this combination to work.

Comment: @DavyM No, it has to be in the Forest class. The reason for that is that in the real code Forest maintains some indices that have to be updated whenever a new child is added.

Comment: Is there a reason to be afraid of a circular reference?

Comment: Well, the usual downsides of circular references: Poor testability, hard to debug, ... Apart from that: The whole thing is a small part of a large legacy codebase with poor code quality. I have spent the better part of the last year refactoring the project, improving the code, writing tests, ..., so now i am pretty reluctant to reintroduce bad style.

Answer (score 0):

If you need action in the forest class to be initiated you can call this in add_child as well. So if vertices need to be updated just update them every time add_child is called. You will need to also keep track of which forest the node is in by passing that into the default constructor.

```
def add_child(self, node):
    node._parent = self
    self._children.append(node)
    self._forest.on_add_child(node)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately that will not work (see edited question). The print statement has to be in the Forest class. Adding a reference to Forest to every node (so that the add_child method could call Forst.on_add_child) is not an option either, because it would introduce a circular dependency.