# Detecting partial updates of a python/cython class property

Tags: python, cython

**Here is the scenario:**

As part of my refactoring process for my 2D rendering cython library, I am removing extraneous "getter/setter" functions to make it more user-friendly. One of the tasks my renderer does is display images on the screen. Currently, I load in an image and extract its pixel data using some `SDL2_image` functions. Then, whenever some image pixel data was modified through that "setter" function, I would notify OpenGL that the updated data would need to be copied from the CPU to the GPU. My goal is to make this "book-keeping" more hidden from the user by exposing an image's pixels as a directly modifiable property and have the CPU <=> GPU synchronization occur behind the scenes.

**Current Code:**

Here is the relevant cython code for my `Image` class (the implementation .pyx file is included only for completeness and is only tangentially related):

**image.pxd**

```
from libs.sdl2 cimport *
from libc.stdint cimport uint8_t, uint32_t, int64_t
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from cpython cimport bool
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray

cdef class Image:
    cdef unsigned int[:, :, :] pixels
    cdef readonly int width
    cdef readonly int height
```

**image.pyx**

```
from libs.sdl2 cimport *
from libc.stdint cimport uint8_t, uint32_t, int64_t
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from cpython cimport bool
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray

cdef int rgba_size = 4

cdef class Image:

    def __cinit__(self, int width, int height, unsigned int[:, :, :] pixels=None):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.pixels = pixels

    def __dealloc__(Image self):
        pass

    @property
    def pixels(self):
        return self.pixels

    @pixels.setter
    def pixels(self, unsigned int[:, :, :] new_pixels):
        self.pixels = new_pixels
        print("updated")

    @staticmethod
    def from_url(str image_url):
        """
        1. Load in an image to an SDL_Surface using SDL_Image module
        2. Convert the image to the SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888 format (right channels for OpenGL's RGBA)
        3. Flip the image as OpenGL spec states texture's BOTTOM-left = (0, 0)!
        """
        cdef Image out
        cdef char * err
        cdef bytes b_image_url = bytes(image_url, "utf-8")
        cdef SDL_Surface *surf = IMG_Load(b_image_url)
        if <int>surf == 0:
            err = IMG_GetError()
            raise ValueError(err)

        cdef SDL_Surface *rgba_surf = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(surf, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888, 0)
        cdef int width = rgba_surf.w
        cdef int height = rgba_surf.h
        cdef uint32_t *pixel_data = <uint32_t *>rgba_surf.pixels

        cdef unsigned int[:, :, :] pixels
        pixels = cvarray(shape=(width, height, rgba_size), itemsize=sizeof(int), format="I")
        cdef int x, y, flipped = 0
        cdef uint32_t abgr = 0
        for y in xrange(height):
            for x in xrange(width):
                flipped = (height - 1 - y) * width + x
                abgr = pixel_data[flipped]
                pixels[x, y, 0] = abgr >> 0 & 0xFF
                pixels[x, y, 1] = abgr >> 8 & 0xFF
                pixels[x, y, 2] = abgr >> 16 & 0xFF
                pixels[x, y, 3] = abgr >> 24 & 0xFF

        SDL_FreeSurface(surf)
        SDL_FreeSurface(rgba_surf)
        out = Image(width, height, pixels=pixels)
        return out
```

This is how I am trying to use my class:

```
from graphics.image import Image
a = Image.from_url("./images/crate.png")
a.pixels[0, 0, 0] = 255#please trigger something that says that pixels has been partially updated!
```

The problem of course is that since only a single value of `pixels` been modified, the `@pixels.setter` decorator is not triggered. The only way to trigger it seems to be replacing the entire memoryview.

**TL;DR: Given an exposed, publicly-modifiable property of a class that is a list/array/np.arrray/memoryview/whatever with multiple sub-values, is there a way to detect transparently whether or not said property has been partially updated within that class?**

Comment: Related (for Python rather than Cython): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665874/python-how-to-have-a-property-and-with-a-setter-function-that-detects-all-chang. There really aren't any Cython specific tricks though

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for the link! I took a look at those options, but it still does not seem like a complete solution. If I use the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` approach, then the semantics of my usage case changes from `a.pixels` to `a[(0, 0)]`. This would work great for accessing individual pixels, but then I could not set all of the pixels at once with a `memoryview` object. This would force the usage of python for-loops to iterate over the pixels (which we both know is slow, hence cython), and the user could not take advantage of numpy to generate pixel data.

Comment: @DavidW Perhaps it is better after all if I just go back to having a `get_pixel()`, `get_pixels()`, `set_pixel()`, and `set_pixels()` set of function to do the work. The alternative I was seeing on that page was creating a wrapper around the pixels data property (like an `ImageData` class that would extend the cython array) but that seems ugly and unwieldy.

Comment: `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` do work with slices too, which should end up being pretty quick. Unfortunately I don't think there is a "nice" solution to this, (or else I'd have answered it)

Comment: @DavidW Thanks, did not realize that was the case, will give it a try. Appreciate your help as always for these types of questions!

Comment: @DavidW One last potential worry point. Would it be possible to resize/reshape the pixel data so that it would have a different width x height if they only have slicing access? Of course, it would probably be silly for a user to do this as they might as well create a different `Image` object but it is something to consider.

Comment: I don't think so. I have another thought though which I'll post shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can get something reasonably efficient with a combination of properties and context managers (for a with statement)

Start by keeping your getter and setter as in the question. Modify your getter so it returns a read only numpy array:

```
@property
def pixels(self):
    r = np.asarray(self._pixels) # gets a view, not a copy
    r.flags['WRITEABLE'] = False
    return r
```

Therefore there shouldn't be any "unmonitored" changes. The setter remains the same and only allows complete replacement of the pixels.

Now define a function that returns a contex manager object:

```
def writeable_pixels(self):
    class WriteablePixelsCtx:
        def __enter__(self2):
            return self._pixels # get the underlying (writeable) memoryview
        def __exit__(self2,*args):
            # update changes 
            # handle any exceptions appropriately (see the main Python documentation on __exit__ for this)
   return WriteablePixelsCtx()
```

You can then do:

```
with im.writeable_pixels() as pixels:
    pixels[i,j] = something
```

and at the end of the block your changes are efficiently dealt with all at once by exit.

What I like about this is:

- Possible to make a whole bunch of small changes with a big update at the end
- Possible to write to pixels efficiently in Cython (it's a memoryview, so you just have to `cdef` a local variable as a memoryview too)

What I dislike is:

- Two different axis mechanisms is a bit messy
- Read access can't be made fast in Cython - memoryviews don't work with read only arrays
- You can manage to write to the saved `pixels`object after the with block. You could avoid this by adding an extra layer of indirection, but that would be significantly slower in Cython.

Comment: I should point out that I haven't tested this, but it's reasonably straightfoward so the idea should work even if the exact code doesn't

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A `with` context does solve this well, although as you said, having a read only property that you get with a separate function is a little odd. To mitigate that, I am adding a setter that just raises an error to tell the user to use the context approach. That being said, making large updates is smarter. Also, contextlib works nicely now in cython for both python 2 and 3, so no need for the embedded class within `writeable_pixels` anymore!

Comment: On second thought, the setter is never called since the user gets a `ValueError: assignment destination is read-only` error instead, making that pointless, so I am scrapping that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've realised it isn't quite as safe as I thought - the writeable object is still writeable after the with block - but I still think it's a reasonably good approach (the intent is pretty clear)

Comment: That looks to be unfortunately true. It is also true for the numpy arrays that can be created from `pixels` that are views into the memoryview. Still, like you said, the syntax is clear. Frustrating that I can't completely idiot-proof the whole thing though lol... There is no way to make typed memoryviews like the pixels property itself readonly on demand right?

Comment: The only option that might work is if I could use a numpy array directly as the `pixels` property instead of a memoryview. Then on exiting the context manager, I could modify the writeable property to make it readonly again. Does not work though since numpy arrays cannot be extension class properties, only local variables...

Comment: Well it turns out even though everything is working reasonably from the cython side now with 3D memoryviews, **OpenGL** can only handle 1-dimensional, fully contiguous arrays when I upload my data to the GPU, even in plain C. Attempting to use my 3D memoryview's pointer gives a texture with random noise since OpenGL does not know where to look. I can copy my data using a loop into the malloc-ed `unsigned int *` that it wants, but needs a slow triple for-loop for every GPU upload! Looks like I might have to scrap this approach for now, which sucks. Still, this was a useful learning experience!

Comment: Numpy arrays (and hence most memoryviews) are stored internally as 1d arrays and you should be able to force it to be contiguous so it doesn't seem impossible. I don't know about efficient Python -> OpenGL data sharing though.

Comment: Are you referring to defining the memoryview as `cdef unsigned int [:, :, ::1] pixels` instead? I have tried that, but that did not seem to help. Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/AnishN/4f781bf5bce14c6e9495682f199a0ec1) that show the conversion I have am doing to circumvent this issue at the moment. Note that this is in my `Texture` class, which has an `Image` class object as one of its properties. I can ask this in a new question if you would prefer.

Comment: That was what I was thinking. I'd suggest a new question (partly because I don't think it's one I can answer...).

Comment: After some more testing and after playing with the various parameters of `glTexImage2D` (the command used to send texture data to the GPU), to fix several other issues, I realized that, while forcing the contiguous layout for the 3D array was working, the issue is that the contiguous `[x][y][r/g/b/a]` 3D layout I am using is **not** equivalent to the 1D data OpenGL wants.  If I were to use a 3D memoryview, it would have to be ordered as `[y][x][r/g/b/a]` in order to iterate through the rows of the image first! Of course, if I do this, then I would have to set pixels backwards as (y, x).

Comment: Good - sounds like you've basically got it working (even if not as simply as you might like...)